# не могу отображать и взоимодиействовать с данными из базы данных

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, redbeanphp

так введённые данные попадают в базу данных во время регистрации
(пользуюсь библиотекой redbeanphp)

```
   $user->username = $data['username'];
   $user->email = $data['email'];
   $user->pass = password_hash($data['pass'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
   R::store($user);
```

всё работает и данные попадают в базу но потом не понимаю как отображать их на другой странице.

вот весь код регистрации.

```
<?php
  require "db.php";

  $data = $_POST;

  if (isset($data['do'])) {

    $errors = '';
    if ( trim($data['username']) == '') {
        $errors = '<p class="notification">Input username!</p>';
        echo $errors; 
    }
    if ( trim($data['email']) == '') {
        $errors = '<p class="notification">Input your email!</p>';
        echo $errors;
    }
    if (trim($data['email']) != '') {
        if ($data['pass'] == '') {
            $errors = '<p class="notification">Input password!</p>';
            echo $errors;
        }   
    } 
    if ($data['pass2'] != $data['pass']) {
        $errors = '<p class="notification">Wrong password</p>';
        echo $errors;
    }
    if (empty($data['age_allow'])) {
      $errors = '<p class="notification">You have to bee=n over 13 years</p>';
      echo $errors;
    }
    if (R::count('users', "email = ?", array($data['email']))) {
      $errors = '<p class="notification">User alredy exist</p>';
      echo $errors;
    }
    if (R::count('users', "username = ?", array($data['username']))) {
      $errors = '<p class="notification">Nickname alredy chosen</p>';
      echo $errors;
    }

  if (empty($errors)) {
        $user = R::dispense('users');
        $user->username = $data['username'];
        $user->email = $data['email'];
        $user->pass = password_hash($data['pass'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        R::store($user);
        echo '<p class="snotification">you are registered</p>';
    }

  }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>StoryBoard</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="register-style.css">
    <style>

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="POST">
        <h2>registration</h2>
        <input class="input1" type="text" name="username" placeholder="choose nickname" value="<?php echo @$data['username'] ?>"><br>
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="enter your email" value="<?php echo @$data['email'] ?>"><br>
        <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="choose password" value="<?php echo @$data['pass'] ?>"><br>
        <input type="password" name="pass2" placeholder="enter password again" value="<?php echo @$data['pass2'] ?>"><br>
        <input type="file" name="avatar" id="avatar">
        <label for="avatar" class="avatar-label">+<br>Avatar</label><br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="age_allow" id="age_allow" value="Yes" checked>
        <label for="age_allow">I am over 13 years</label><br><br><br><br>
        <a href="sign_in.php" class="registrationa">have an account?</a><br>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-block" type="submit" name="do">enjoy!</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

вот подключенный файл db.php

```
<?php  
    require "rb.php";
    R::setup( 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=storyboard',
        'root', '', '' );

    session_start();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Всмысле на другой странице?
Если ты хочешь после регистрации автоматически авторизовать пользователя, то ты можешь сохранить `id` нового пользователя, а затем загрузить его в переменную `$_SESSION['auth_user']`, примерно так.

```
<?php
    $user = R::dispense('users');
    $user->username = $data['username'];
    $user->email = $data['email'];
    $user->pass = password_hash($data['pass'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    $uId = R::store($user);
    $_SESSION['auth_user'] = R::load('users',$uId);
    header('location: '.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

    //После перезагрузки страницы выводишь данные о юзере из переменной
    $user = $_SESSION['auth_user'];
    print 'Привет - '.$user->username;
?>
```

Но если ты хочешь загружать пользователей, то тебе необходимо воспользоваться:

```
<?php
   $find = R::findOne('users','username = ?',[$data['name']]); 
?>
```

На сайте RedBeanPHP всё есть - https://redbeanphp.com